# Is there a way to install a rootkit without kernel headers?

Tags: rootkits

I was just wonderin, is there a way to create a rootkit without the kernel header files? I'm trying to have fun with a mips device and I'm curious if there is another way to infect it.

Comment: The WDK (Windows Driver Kit) is free from Microsoft.